# How to get text from a specific column of a row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code I can access each row in my html table.

```
$("#table").find("tr:not(:has(th))").each(function (index) {                                                                                            
    $(this) --> is the row
  });
```

But inside the function how can I access the text of a particular column?

Comment: Which column? Please be more specific.

Comment: @Felix:E.g 3rd or 4th

Answer (score 2):

you can access the columns in many ways, one possible solution could be,

```
var tds = $(this).children('td');
tds.eq(0) // 1st one
tds.eq(1) // 2nd one
tds.eq(n) // nth one
```

and you can access its text by using jquery's `.text()` function,

```
console.log(tds.eq(0).text());
```

Comment: But how to get the text if the column?

Comment: The column has text.So $(this).text is the text in the row. How can I get the text displayed in the column using your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.find()` along with `.eq()` and `.text()` to get the text of your column:

```
var text = $(this).find('td').eq(2).text(); // Get text of third column
```